# search input field according to the value (API)

Tags: api

I have an api call like this: api/zipCode/${zipCode}

So, I have an input field and the user enters the zip code and what I want to make is if the user enters 3 digits I want to show the matched zip codes. For example,e if the user enters 123 I want to show 123, 1234, 1233 etc. Since I have no idea how to build this, I am looking for you helps. Any idea would be precious.

Comment: Which front-end technology you are using? I will give you a solution according to that.

Comment: I am using React but also using Redux

Comment: Give me some time, I will give you the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the solution below

Also, You can see the live demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-lichterman-1rqjf?file=/src/App.js:0-1190

```
import { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";

const endPoint = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      const res = await fetch(endPoint);
      const data = await res.json();
      setUsers(data);
      setLoading(false);
    })();
  }, []);

  const filterData = useMemo(() => {
    if (searchText.length > 3) {
      return users.filter((user) => user.address.zipcode.includes(searchText));
    }
    return null;
  }, [users, searchText]);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Type in searchbox to get the user with matching zipcode</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search Zip"
        value={searchText}
        onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
      />
      <ul>
        {filterData &&
          filterData.map((data) => (
            <li key={data.id}>{data.address.zipcode}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly splendid but my endpoint is quite different as you see. I get zipcodes if you write zipcode at the end of the endpoint. Could you also give me an idea how I can approach?

Comment: So, If I am not getting wrong you want, whenever search text length is greater than 3 you want to send a request to the server to get the matching zip code list? Also, can you give me your endpoint or matching endpoint so that I can give you solutions?

Comment: my endpoint is ike this: api/cities/get_with_zip/${zipCode}